# How to Associate a User Role to a Custom Entity with ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-roles

In my ASP.NET Core Application I have created two Roles:

1. CompanyAdministrator
2. CompanyViewer

`Company` is an entity on my database.

Any user can create a `Company` and be an CompanyAdministrator of it.

However, if one user provides access to another user as CompanyViewer for one `Company`, the new user will not be allowed to manage users in this `Company`.

So as a user, I can access a lot of companies. Some of those I will be a Administrator, and on others I will be just a Viewer.

Also there will be companies created by others users where I will not have any permission to access.

The question is: how can I relate a specific Role to an User and a Company at same time?

The are some code that I have ultil now:

The User Model:

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{        
    public virtual IList<CompanyUser> Companies { get; set; }
}
```

The Company Model:

```
public class Company
{
    public long ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Users")]
    public virtual IList<CompanyUser> Users { get; set; }
}
```

The Model to Control Relationship (I will rename it to CompanyPermission):

```
public class CompanyUser
{
    [ForeignKey("Company")]
    public long CompanyID { get; set; }

    public Company Company { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
    [MaxLength(450)]
    public string UserID { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    public CompanyUserRole Role { get; set; }
}

public enum CompanyUserRole
{
    Administrator = 1,
    Viewer = 2
}
```

How I'm checking if some ser has permission to edit a Company:

```
ApplicationUser appUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
var currentCompany = await _context.Company.Include(c => c.Users).SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);

if (!currentCompany.Users.Where(c => c.UserID == appUser.Id && c.Role == CompanyUserRole.Administrator).Any())
{
    return NotFound();
}
```

How I'm creating the Roles I intend to use instead of the code above:

```
var companyAdminRole = await _roleManager.FindByNameAsync("CompanyAdmin");
        if (companyAdminRole == null)
        {
            companyAdminRole = new IdentityRole("CompanyAdmin");
            await _roleManager.CreateAsync(companyAdminRole);

            await _roleManager.AddClaimAsync(companyAdminRole, new Claim("Permission", "company.view"));
            await _roleManager.AddClaimAsync(companyAdminRole, new Claim("Permission", "company.update"));
            await _roleManager.AddClaimAsync(companyAdminRole, new Claim("Permission", "company.users.view"));
            await _roleManager.AddClaimAsync(companyAdminRole, new Claim("Permission", "company.users.manage"));
            await _roleManager.AddClaimAsync(companyAdminRole, new Claim("Permission", "company.analitycs.view"));
            await _roleManager.AddClaimAsync(companyAdminRole, new Claim("Permission", "company.analitycs.download"));
        }

        var companyViewerRole = await _roleManager.FindByNameAsync("CompanyViewer");
        if (companyViewerRole == null)
        {
            companyViewerRole = new IdentityRole("CompanyViewer");
            await _roleManager.CreateAsync(companyViewerRole);

            await _roleManager.AddClaimAsync(companyViewerRole, new Claim("Permission", "company.view"));
            await _roleManager.AddClaimAsync(companyViewerRole, new Claim("Permission", "company.analitycs.view"));
            await _roleManager.AddClaimAsync(companyViewerRole, new Claim("Permission", "company.analitycs.download"));
        }
```

Comment: Until now I did create a model/table to make a many-to-many relationship between the models User and Company. That model has a property that says if the user is Administrator or just a Viewer of the company.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: HI John, I just add the code on the description as asked